# Script function to check if IP is whitelisted

Tags: python, sql, function, whitelist

I have a Python script which blocks some IPs if they perform some actions. This script contains a function to check if the IP is already blocked. In addition to this, I'd like the function to also check if the IP is stored in a database table and if it is, do not block it ( whitelist )

The function looks like this :

```
def check_ip(ip_address):
    cmd = "/sbin/iptables -L INPUT -n|grep " + ip_address
    signal,output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    if signal is 0:
        return True
    else:
    return False
```

I'm not that versed in Python so I'm not sure on how to go with this but I imagine it's pretty simple. I'm thankful for any suggestions you might have. Thank you !

Later Edit : I want to use a MySQL database as I'll be writing a PHP interface to manually add IPs. How would I search for that ? The table only has 2 fields : id and whitelist_ip, the latter storing the IP which needs to be whitelisted.

Comment: I also forgot to add that the name of the table is actually whitelist and it only contains 2 rows : id and whitelist_ip which contains the actual IP address.

Comment: Can you elaborate about ```/sbin/iptables -L INPUT -n|grep```? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on editing this whitelist manually, you could just use a file with your list of IP addresses. (one per line) You could then use code something like this to check it:

```
def check_ip(ip_address):
    cmd = "/sbin/iptables -L INPUT -n|grep " + ip_address
    signal,output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    if signal is 0:
        return True
    whitelist = open('<filename>')
    for ip in whitelist.readlines():
        if ip_address == ip:
            return True
    return False
```

This will first check using the check you've made, and if that fails, it will check the ip whitelist. Because the function returns from the if-clause, the else clause is not needed.

If you want to use an sql database to store the whitelist data, I'd recommend using mysql or sqlite. Both of these have python wrappers available.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use a MySQL database as I'll be writing a PHP interface to manually add IPs. How would I search for that ? The table only has 2 fields : id and whitelist_ip, the latter storing the IP which needs to be whitelisted.

Comment: you'll want to look at a python package called MySQLdb. You can find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/forums/forum/70461/topic/1653833

Comment: But how do I implement this in the coding ? That's what I'm interested about.

Comment: I don't know much about mysqldb. I'll make this a community wiki post so anyone with the info can edit it.